# Table Row Highlight When Clicked - Not highlighting first row

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        TV Schedules
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
        <table class='table table-striped table-inverse font_styling table-hover' id='tv_schedule_table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class='center_text sorttable' width='25%'>Show Name&nbsp; <span class='fa fa-caret-down'></span> <span class='fa fa-caret-up'></span></th>
                    <th class='center_text sorttable' width='25%'>Episode&nbsp; <span class='fa fa-caret-down'></span> <span class='fa fa-caret-up'></span></th>
                    <th class='center_text sorttable'>Date Aired&nbsp; <span class='fa fa-caret-down'></span> <span class='fa fa-caret-up'></span></th>
                    <th width='10%'></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id='tv_schedule_row'>
                    <td class='center_text cell_width' width='25%'>{{tv_show.show_name}}</td>
                    <td class='center_text clickable_cell' width='25%'>{{tv_show.season_episode}}</td>
                    <td class='center_text clickable_cell' width='20%'>{{tv_show.date_aired}}</td>
                    <td class='center_text w3-large' width='15%'><i class='fa fa-check icon-styling' style='margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;'></i> <i class='fa fa-trash icon-styling' style='margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;'></i> <i class='fa fa-search icon-styling' style='margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;'></i> <i class='fa fa-plus icon-styling' style='margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;'></i></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the function called to hightlight row:

```
$scope.alter_show = function(show, index)
{
    $scope.editing_show = true;

    var line_no = index+1;
    var table   = document.getElementById("tv_schedule_table");
    var cells   = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); 

    cells[line_no].className = "hover_click_cell selected_click_cell";
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work for the first row but from row 2 onwards, it works. I'm not too sure where I am going wrong here.

Comment: var line_no = index; Remove the +1

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of index at the start?

Remember the "cells" object will be 0 indexed, so the first "tr" element would be tr[0]

Comment: The index is 0 as it should be, but if I removed the +1 it higlights the table heading instead of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Check updated code

```
$scope.alter_show = function(show, index)
{
    $scope.editing_show = true;
    var line_no = index;
    var table   = document.getElementById("tv_schedule_table");
    var cells   = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr"); 
    cells[line_no].className = "hover_click_cell selected_click_cell";
}
```

Comment: This is still doing the same thing and not highlighting the first row. However, it's not highlighting the header row now though...